# Taking a string in an SQL Server table and searching on Google

Tags: sql-server, r, google-search-api

My query is related to how to build a module to take the string in a column in an SQL Server table, search on Google and scan search results for keywords and if the keywords are found put them into another column in the same table.

My initial idea was to use an R - SQL Server hybrid solution. But your guidance on any other possible tools would be great. I know it is an open ended question but I am looking more for guidance than a solution right now.

So basic steps I could gather...

1. Get strings in the column from SQL Server into R
2. Use RCurl to perform search of terms in R imported data.
3. Search for keywords I am looking for in the Google search results.
4. If results are what I am looking for, set a flag in SQL Server, else skip.

Comment: Maybe you could use the google search API together with library httr?

Comment: Using httr looks like a good option. But in order to scan the contents of the search for the pre-determined keywords, do I do it in R and does it have to be done on the <content> output in raw mode or parsed mode?

Comment: I haven't used httr that much, only in a course. So I do not have a full answer.